# Override TableRow styling on TableCell

Tags: javafx

so I have the following problem.
I have a JavaFX TableView, where all the Cells has the same styling but one. For that one cell I would like to remove all the styling, but I guess the RowFactory has some priority or whatever.

I have some kind of code like that:

**FXML**

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="tcolNoStyle"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="tcolStyled"/>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

**Controller**

```
public class TableController {
    @FXML
    TableView<TableData> tableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData, String> tcolNoStyle;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData, String> tcolStyled;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        tableView.setRowFactory(row -> new RowFactory());
        tcolNoStyle.setCellFactory(cell -> new CellFactoryForNoStyling());
    }
}
```

**The Data behind the table**

```
public class TableData {
    public final SimpleStringProperty noStyleTextProperty;
    public final SimpleStringProperty styledTextProperty;

    public TableData(){
        noStyleTextProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
        styledTextProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }
}
```

**RowFactory**

```
public class RowFactory extends TableRow<TableData> {
    public RowFactory(){
        itemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null){
                setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: right");
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

**CellFactory that one no styled Cell**

```
public class CellFactoryForNoStyling extends TableCell<TableData, String> {
    public CellFactoryForNoStyling(){
        super();
        setStyle(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setStyle(null);
    }
}
```

So what I want is, that only that one column should have no style

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the fact that the `-fx-text-alignment` property is inherited. `setStyle(null)` only makes sure there are no additional changes done for the node it's called for.

The probably simplest option would be to simply specify the default value using `setStyle`:

```
public CellFactoryForNoStyling() {
    setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: left");
}
```

You could leave the styling to a CSS stylesheet though. This is much more convenient than using inline styles, since it's much easier this way to deal with selection, focus, ect.

You could e.g. add the following stylesheet to the scene; this way you do not to use a custom `cellValueFactory`/`rowFactory`:

```css
/* default cell style */
.my-table .table-cell {
    -fx-text-alignment: right;
}

/* overwrite above style using selector with higher specifity */
.my-table .table-cell.unstyled {
    -fx-text-alignment: inherit;
}
```

```xml
<TableView fx:id="tableView" styleClass="my-table"> <!-- style class added here-->
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="tcolNoStyle" styleClass="unstyled"/> <!-- style class added here -->
        <TableColumn fx:id="tcolStyled"/>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```